# Is it possible to extract an icon from an old Visual Studio project?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I have an old VB project that I'm converting from WinForms into WPF. I was re-creating the user interface without problems until I tried to locate the Icon that the old application uses. I can't find it in the project files and I can't see a way in visual studio to export it.

Anyone know of a way to accomplish this? I'd like to keep the UI as close to the old UI as possible (users don't like change).

Comment: You can use software like Icon Sucker. I haven't used it in a million years, but is probably still available. It extracts the icon from any file.

Comment: IcoFX is one such tool but there are many other

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was hoping there was a way to do it from within Visual Studio, but it appears there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract icon resources from your file. See a free app to do it:

nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html